# Redirect or add missing category alias to URL in Joomla 3.6

Tags: joomla-3.x, url, sef, redirect, category

how can I redirect a URL in Joomla 3.6 from:

```
domain.tld/articleid-my-seo-title.html
```

to

```
domain.tld/category-alias/articleid-my-seo-title.html
```

I need to do this because Google sometimes seems to index the pages without the category-alias and I want to do a 301 to the URL with alias.

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using a Canonical Link plugin?  That would essentially do the same thing and affect everything across the board.

Comment: I am not sure if this plugin will help, because the pages without the category-alias in the URL only show the meta tags of the content page, but not the right content. So I think it will be a better option to redirect to the content page with the right content.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the core Joomla! Redirects component.

Documentation: https://docs.joomla.org/Help36:Components_Redirect_Manager